# Permitted request not allowed

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have added custom filters in the security configuration class. I want to allow any user to register them in the application. A security filter chain is blocking every request I have permitted in the security config class. I have to filter requests in the `JwtAuthenticationFilter` class to allow users to register them.

Every time a permitted URI is called, JwtAuthenticationFilter blocks the request.

**Security Configuration class**

```
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final CustomAuthenticationManager customAuthenticationManager;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests(
                        authorize ->
                                authorize.requestMatchers(
                                                "/ss023/user/register",
                                                "/ss023/user/getStringTwo",
                                                "/css/**",
                                                "/register",
                                                "/login"
                                        )
                                        .permitAll()
                                        .anyRequest()
                                        .authenticated()
                )
                .addFilterAt(
                        new CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(customAuthenticationManager, new JwtTokenService()),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class
                )
                .addFilterAfter(
                        new JwtAuthenticationFilter(new JwtTokenService(), userDetailsService),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class
                        /*CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class*/
                )
                .build();
    }
}
```

**Custom Authentication filter chain class**

```
@Component
public class CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private final CustomAuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final JwtTokenService jwtTokenService;

    public CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(CustomAuthenticationManager authenticationManager1, JwtTokenService jwtTokenService) {
        super(authenticationManager1);
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager1;
        this.jwtTokenService = jwtTokenService;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        Login loginUser;
        try {
            loginUser = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), Login.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                loginUser.getUsername(),
                loginUser.getPassword(),
                new ArrayList<>()
        );

        return authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
                                            HttpServletResponse response,
                                            FilterChain chain,
                                            Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String principal = (String) authResult.getPrincipal();
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authResult.getAuthorities();
        String token = null;
        Map<String, String> accessToken = new HashMap<>();

        // Create Jwt token
        try {
            token = jwtTokenService.generateToken(principal, authorities);
            accessToken.put("access_token", token);
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        // Add Bearer token in authorization header
        response.addHeader(JwtProperties.HEADER_STRING, JwtProperties.TOKEN_PREFIX + token);

        // Send access token as response
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write("{ \n \"access_token\" : "
                + "\"" + accessToken.get("access_token") + "\""
                + "\n}"
        );
    }
}
```

**Jwt Authentication Filter chain class**

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtTokenService jwtTokenService;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;



    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String path = request.getRequestURI();
        System.out.println(path);
        if (!request.getRequestURI().equals("/ss023/user/register")) {

            String authToken = jwtTokenService.getToken(request);

            if (null != authToken) {

                String username = jwtTokenService.getUsernameFromToken(authToken);

                if (null != username) {

                    UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

                    if (jwtTokenService.validateToken(authToken, userDetails)) {
                        Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                                userDetails,
                                null,
                                userDetails.getAuthorities()
                        );
                        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
                        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                    } else {
                        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                        response.setContentType("application/json");
                        response.getWriter().write("{\"error\":\"Bearer Token Expired\"}");
                    }
                } else {
                    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                    response.setContentType("application/json");
                    response.getWriter().write("{\"error\":\"Wrong bearer token\"}");
                }
            } else {
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                response.setContentType("application/json");
                response.getWriter().write("{\"error\":\"No bearer token\"}");
            }
        } else {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a breakpoint at `if (!request.getRequestURI().equals("/ss023/user/register")) {` and check if URL is matching. It depend on you context path.

Answer (score 0):

"/ss023/user/register" is the correct api url path?

debug on line: `if (!request.getRequestURI().equals("/ss023/user/register")) {`

I prefer to use in start of doFilterInternal method:

```
if (request.getServletPath().contains("/register")) {
  filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
  return;
}
```

Your code is correct, debugging you can find the error.

Its works?